# Difference between 'amazing at' and 'amazing in'

Tags: prepositions

> She is amazing ---------- painting.

What's the difference between **amazing at** and **amazing in**?

What would be used, **at** or **in**? And also tell me what is the grammatical role of **painting** in the sentence.

Comment: Referring to your comment about the grammatical role of painting: **at** and **in** are both prepositions: they require a noun. Words derived from verbs and ending in **-ing** are either participles (which act like adjectives) or gerunds (which act like nouns). In this case a noun is required, so you know that it's a gerund. Many activities are described by gerunds: riding, skiing, swimming, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I feel like *amazing at/in* will (more or less) follow the same pattern as *good at/in*. This is likely because the two words reflect something positive about the subject.

*In* and *at* are sometimes interchangeable. In this case, I would use *at*:

> 1. She is **good** at painting. → She is **amazing** at painting*.

According to [this post](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/good-at-good-in-and-good-with/), *good at* is generally used with activities.  It provides other examples:

> 2. He’s good at football.
> 3. She’s good at product design.
> 4. Her mother is good at Trivial Pursuit.
> 5. When Fatima was only six, she was good at drawing.

In each case, you can swap *good* with *amazing* and each case remains idiomatic.

The post also makes a note about academics. It says

> When it comes to school subjects, both “good at” and “good in” are used.

For example,

> 6. Max is good at math.
> 7. Max is good in math.

Of course, these are general guidelines. There are exceptions.

> 8. She's good in bed

This means *she's good **at** sex*. You cannot replace *in* with *at* in 8 because *bed* is not an activity.

This can sometimes be extended to other places where activities are done (as [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7307/good-at-or-good-in) points out), for example

> 9. He's good in the kitchen. (He's good at cooking; He cooks well.)

You can swap *good* with *amazing* in the previous examples and they should sound fine. Other positive descriptions, like *skillful*, should work too. Again, this is a rough guideline and there probably more exceptions.

---

<sub>*You can rewrite this as "She is an amazing painter." I prefer this over the original, although the original is ok.</sub>

Comment: Your "exceptions" both refer to physical places: you would also say "he is in the kitchen" and not "at the kitchen". The trick here is that in examples 1 - 5, you directly mention the activity they are good at. In examples 8 and 9, you don't mean literally that he is a good person in the kitchen but not in the living room; rather "bed" and "kitchen" are locations that stand for the activities "sex" and "cooking", respectively. Similarly, you would say "he is good with a ball" because that is what you hold when you are good _at_ (for example) football.

Answer (score 2):

The main distinction, though it is somewhat blurred, is that **at** is used mainly with activities requiring our physical attendance and participation, and **in** is used mainly with  *domains* or *areas*  or *circumstances* or *environments*.

We can be good at ping pong, guessing games, or calming a frightened child.

Someone (or something) can be good in the kitchen, in delicate situations, in the board room, in chemistry,  in times of political unrest.

> The camel is good in the desert.
>
> Stainless steel is good in the salt-air.

The virtues of the camel and the stainless steel are manifest in those particular environments.

Some activities can be understood in either manner.  When we say

*She is good at math*

we are presenting her as someone who can solve number problems, or who offers answers in algebra class, that is, "math" is presented as an activity in which she participates.

And when we say

*She is good in math*

we are presenting math as a domain of knowledge, an area of intellectual pursuit.

P.S.  **Good** means "possessing *some* skill or virtue", not "showing mastery" or "possessing unparalleled excellence". So it would be comical to say

> Albert Einstein was good at physics.
>
> Beethoven was good at music.
>
> Pelé was good at soccer.

We can be "amazing","terrible", "fantastic", "horrible", "so-so", "excellent", "very good" or "not very good", or even "a genius" at or in something.

Comment: What about computers? "She is amazing (or *good*)  *at* / *in* computers,"

Comment: Would you recommend a learner to say [*The camel is good in the desert*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22The+camel+is+good+in+the+desert%22)?

Comment: It depends on how the speaker (consciously or unconsciously) thinks of computers.  **Computers** could refer to a domain of knowledge (computer science) or to devices we interact with.  Either would be acceptable.

Comment: You see, I'd be inclined to say that someone is good *with* computers.

Comment: **with** is a viable option. **With** emphasizes instrumentality. **at** suggests "knows how to work these gadgets"; "in" suggests "computers as domain of knowledge".

Comment: What do you find amiss with "The camel is good in the desert"?

Comment: First of all, I think it sounds unnatural, and secondly, it is also ambiguous. It sounds as though a camel is a good (it behaves well) in the desert.  If we are talking about ability, what is a camel *good at doing*  in the desert? E.g. A Land Rover is good *for driving* **in** the desert.

Comment: "Good" there would be understood by native speakers to refer to virtues or capabilities which are beneficial in the desert. No native speaker would understand it to mean "behaves well" in the sense of "doesn't misbehave like an unruly child". Compare *A Jeep is good in rough terrain*.

Comment: As to its sounding "unnatural", you're free to trust your own ear over mine, of course, but as the native speaker here, I trust mine over yours. Isn't your native tongue Italian?